# how can I detect that option value has changed in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress plugin and I want to fire a different action based on each option value change. so how can I do that ?

Example:

```
$options = get_option('ACP_settings'); if $options['acp-select'] has changed from previous value than I want to fire different action based on selection
```

Please note that `$option['acp-select']` is retrieved from `select/option html form` and has following values for `selection:'book','air','SW','HW'` and etc....

I hope I have posted my question clearly.

thanks for help

Comment: You could use the hooks based around updating/adding meta and check if the key is equal to ACP_settings each time.

Comment: I tried to find update related hook in wordpress codex but nothing found OR may be I missed it, thanks for your inputs

Comment: Perhaps http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_update_option_(option_name)

Answer (score 3):

You can use wordpress hooks in the [update_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) function.

In your case you can use `updated_option` or `update_option_{$option}` hooks.

The code for `ACP_settings` option would look like:

```
add_action( 'update_option_ACP_settings', function($old_value, $value, $option){

    if( $old_value !== $value ){
        // Your option was updated
        // Run your code here       
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I'm facing this issue currently and looking for solution, what if you want to save something that you don't know what the old value might be... for instance i am trying to save an API key and when the API key is changed to another key, i want the option to be updated and the value of the API key to be updated on another option name. How do i go about such using your answer. Thanks

Comment: @KolawoleEmmanuelIzzy 
Not sure I understand right, but still try to answer.

To use `updated_option` or `update_option_{$option}` hooks you need to know only "Option Name" not "Option Value".
The `$old_value` variable will be passed into the callback function by WordPress (just like the "New Option Value" `$value` and "Option Name" itself `$option`).
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_option/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option_option/

Comment: Oh! thanks ... I was confused on the `$old_value` and `$value` ... Good to know wordpress handles the checking of old and new value. Thanks so much @Alexander

Comment: I have tried the above code but still not updating the other options i want to up.I have asked a question regarding what i want to achieve with [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346847/updating-woocommerce-settings-api-when-wordpress-settings-api-saved-and-vise-ver) here before i show this question. Not sure if this answer is the best approach